# Tomcat Spring - 8 mins taken to create Spring Webapplication context in local workspace

Tags: performance, spring, tomcat

I am facing a pecuilar issue with my Tomcat server. The issue is that my web application context takes about 8 mins to be created for a single startup.

Usually what seems to be happening for my team is that the first start up finsihes in around 10 mins and susbequent restarts only take around 2 - 3 mins. However all my start up takes 8 - 9 mins.

This is a custoized version of Tomcat that is being used so I dont have a version.sh file to actually determine which is the version of tomcat that is being used exactly. We are using version 2.5 of Spring

******************************* Trace from Logs
A Trace from the logs 
DEBUG 2012-12-10 15:24:36,377 | --> createWebApplicationContext

DEBUG 2012-12-10 15:33:54,953 ... log continues

---

The log above shows nearly 9 mins to create the web application context

As per my analysis there are 2 ways this could happen.

1. My system is really low on memory _;However this cannot be the case as I am using a 3 GB RAM and there is sufficient memory.
2. There is some properties in Tomcat which needs to be changed to start to a faster boot up.

   Would be great if anybody out there can give me some ideas as to why this might happen so that I can get started on investigating more about this.

Comment: you should mention what your app is doing in WebApplicationContext startup

Comment: If you are using a lot of libraries and component scanning through `<context:component-scan base-package="xxxx"/>` make sure xxxx is as limited as possible or you may end up with scanning too many jars which can easily take several minutes.

Comment: Subin and mrembisz, We are basically instatiating a lot of beans which includes hibernate beans, webservice proxies, service beans etc. However the problem is that this is a problem which occurs only for me and not among my other team members. So it cant be a problem with WebApplicationContext or context scan is what I am assuming

Comment: Maybe you have some issues with your database? Locks pending? Tomcat usually takes seconds to startup and maybe half a minute to configure the spring context. Ensure you don't have anything blocking the network, db, I/O, ... you can also enable the spring debug. As it takes already 8 minutes to initiate you will probably have some pauses in the logs

Answer (score 0):

Increase the memory in catalina.sh

`JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-server -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m
-XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=256m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"`